# css: How get rid of this extra white space after and before text?

Tags: php, css, whitespace, margin

Here's an image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXr5f.png]

The HTML is in a php which is as follows:

```
print "<p class = 'Back'>Epic Fail</p>";
print "<p>You forgot to put in your Username or Password.</p>";
```

The CSS for the Back class and p is as follows:

```
p.Back
{
font-size: 200px;
display: block;
text-align: left;
font-style: oblique;
}
p
{
font-size: 20px;
color: #292421;
font-family: Times;
}
```

This is all wrapped in a div tag that has around 25px padding, why is there so much white space? It's a problem because it creates a scroll bar which I don't want and it doesn't look very good.

EDIT:
Here's the div:

```
#login
{
background: #E0DFDB;
width: 1200px;
margin: auto;
}
```

I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome (Sorry for not specifying)
The scroll bar is successfully removed by taking away the padding from the login div and the line-height. However, there is still the white space and I have thoroughly ran through all of my code to see if I've added anything to the p tag but I couldn't find anything. Is there a site where I can upload all of my code to show you guys?

RESULT:

Thanks guys, I decided to use the web dev tool that came with google chrome and IT TURNS OUT: THE MARGIN BY DEFAULT SOMEHOW GOT SET TO 200PX??!! so all I had to do was just set the margin for p to auto

Comment: What scroll bar?  It looks fine for me (in Chrome):  http://jsfiddle.net/Rz9hE/  I think some of the other styles you have on your actual page must be causing some side-effects, as the code you posted seems to work fine in isolation.

Comment: Yeah, removing the padding and line-height takes away the scroll bar but I cant seem to get rid of that huge space between 'epic fail' and 'you forgot'

Comment: Also, note that HTML attributes and their values should not contain spaces. `<p class='Back'>Epic Fail</p>`

Comment: Hm, I could reuse your "Epic fail" idea for my IE8 visitors... `:P`

Comment: Could you post your own jsfiddle so we can take a look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because, by default, Chrome applies a style of `-webkit-margin-before: 1em; -webkit-margin-after: 1em` to `p` elements.  In your example, this would create a `200px` margin above and below the element.  Setting `margin: auto` or any other `margin` value overrides this default.

Other browsers apply a default margin to `p` elements in different ways: e.g. Firefox applies `margin: 1em 0` which results in the same effect.

The margin does not appear on jsfiddle because they employ a reset stylesheet which gives `p` elements `margin: 0`.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a JSFiddle version of the code you've posted -- see http://jsfiddle.net/RukbS/

In my JSFiddle, I can't see the massive empty space beneath the "Epic Fail" which is in your screenshot, so I guess there's something in the code you're running which you haven't shown us.

Without seeing your code actually in action, it's hard to know what the difference is between it and the version I've created, but looking at the screenshot, it looks very much as if the "Epic Fail" paragraph has run over two lines.

The only way I could get my test to replicate this was by putting `<br><br>` immediately after the word "Fail". I'm assuming you're not doing that.

You might want to consider dropping the `line-height` attribute from the stylesheet. It isn't really achieving much (as it will pick up that size anyway due to the font size), and is the sort of thing that might be causing what you're seeing. If you really do want a bit of extra space around the text, use `padding` or `margin` instead; it's easier to control than `line-height`.

You didn't state which browser you're using that shows this effect. It is possible that you're seeing something that only shows up in certain browsers. Most browsers these days come with a good debugging tool which can help isolate issues like this. In Firefox, you'll need to install the Firebug plugin; in most other modern browsers, the Developer Tools feature is built in.

Open the Firebug/Dev Tools window, and use it to find the "Epic Fail" element. It will allows you to examine the size and shape of the element, and what styles are being applied to it. This will almost certainly give you the information you need to work out what the problem is.

I know I haven't given you an answer that directly solves the problem, but I hope some of the things I've pointed out here will lead you in the right direction to finding the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to use the web dev tool that came with google chrome and IT TURNS OUT: THE MARGIN BY DEFAULT SOMEHOW GOT SET TO 200PX??!! so all I had to do was just set the margin for p to auto.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but the combination of

1. `padding` on the `div` and
2. extra `line-height`

might be causing the excess.

Right now, your adding

- 50px from `padding` (25px on top and bottom)
- 50px from `line-height` (which is 50px more than the `font-size`)

---

I tried your current code in a fiddle and it seems to work fine (drag the bar to the left to see the entire screen)

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/aNRhN/

Perhaps there is other code being inserted with the PHP?

Or you have other styles applied to the `p`.

Comment: I can't find any other styles added to p that affects spacing. I ony specified things such as color and font elements